# Maven not working on eclipse on centos 7

Tags: eclipse, maven

When I try to run maven from the "Run As" build it gives me error on console on eclipse

> /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java

Comment: We need much more details (error message etc.). Please _edit_ your question.

Comment: This is what I have been getting... Which is causing more frustration. No error is displayed but this line on console.

Comment: Try a build from the command line (with mvn).

Comment: @JFMeier it is running from command line. But why not from eclipse editor?

Comment: I am selecting "External Maven" rather than selecting the "Emedded Maven"(Pre Installed Maven in Eclipse) option. 
But when I run the Maven with the Embedded version it works. And it doesn't with External Maven

Comment: This is a Spring Boot application.